Signing a PDF through iText with the use signature from external web service(digidentity)
I create an empty container for a digital signature, then get the hash of the file and send it to the digidentity service for signature. After this I receive a response - a digital signature in the form of a string.
Next, I embed this line into the container created in the file. But I can't get validated on the site
https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation
And I get an error in this service
enter image description here
public HashInfo[] ConvertHashToBase64(string[] filePaths, JsonData identityInfo, string uniqueId)
{
    SPWeb cWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    List<HashInfo> hashInfos = new List<HashInfo>();

    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        var signInstance = new PAdESSignerClass();
        signInstance.EmptySignature(signedPath, aWeb, identityInfo, uniqueId);
        SPFile file = aWeb.GetFile(filePath);
        var fileStream = signedFile.OpenBinary();
                
        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(fileStream);
            string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

            hashInfos.Add(new HashInfo
            {
                Hash = base64Hash,
                UniqueId = file.UniqueId,
                FileName = file.Name
            });
        }
    }

    return hashInfos.ToArray();
}

public class PAdESSignerClass
{
    public void EmptySignature(string containerFilePath, SPWeb web, JsonData jsonData, string guidString)
    {
        SPFile file = web.GetFile(containerFilePath);
        var cert = jsonData.cert;
        string certificate = cert.certificates[0].ToString();
        byte[] certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificate);
        X509Certificate2 xcertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
        IBouncyCastleFactory FACTORY = BouncyCastleFactoryCreator.GetFactory();
        IX509Certificate[] iTextCertificates2 = FACTORY.CreateX509CertificateParser().ReadAllCerts(xcertificate.GetRawCertData()).ToArray();

        using (Stream fileStream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader reader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(fileStream);
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, memoryStream, new StampingProperties());
                signer.GetSignatureAppearance().SetCertificate(iTextCertificates2[0]);
                signer.SetFieldName(guidString);

                iText.Signatures.IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

                signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192);

                byte[] pdfBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                web.Files.Add(containerFilePath, pdfBytes, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddSignatureToPdf(string certPath, JsonData jsonData, string containerFilePath, byte[]  signatureHash, SPWeb web, string uniqueId, string timestamp)
    {
        var cert = jsonData.cert;
        string certificate = cert.certificates[0].ToString();
        byte[] certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificate);

        SPFile file = web.GetFile(containerFilePath);

        using (Stream fileStream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(fileStream);
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(pdfDoc, memoryStream, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.StampingProperties());

                X509Certificate2 xcertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
                   
                IBouncyCastleFactory FACTORY = BouncyCastleFactoryCreator.GetFactory();
                IX509Certificate[] iTextCertificates2 = FACTORY.CreateX509CertificateParser().ReadAllCerts(xcertificate.GetRawCertData()).ToArray();
                IPrivateKey iTextPrivateKey = FACTORY.CreateRsa2048KeyPairGenerator().GenerateKeyPair().GetPrivateKey();

                signer.GetSignatureAppearance();

                iText.Signatures.IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(iTextPrivateKey, iTextCertificates2, signatureHash, certificateBytes, timestamp);

                PdfSigner.SignDeferred(signer.GetDocument(), uniqueId, memoryStream, external);
        
                byte[] signedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                web.Files.Add(containerFilePath, signedBytes, true);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyExternalSignatureContainer : iText.Signatures.IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    private readonly byte[] signedBytes;
    protected IPrivateKey pk;
    protected IX509Certificate[] chain;
    protected byte[] signatureHash;
    protected byte[] certificateBytes;
    protected string timestamp;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(IPrivateKey pk, IX509Certificate[] chain, byte[]signatureHash, byte[] certificateBytes, string timestamp)
    {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.chain = chain;
        this.signatureHash = signatureHash;
        this.certificateBytes = certificateBytes;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream inputStream)
    {
        byte[] encodedSig = null;
        iText.Signatures.PrivateKeySignature signature = new iText.Signatures.PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256");
        string digestAlgorithmName = signature.GetDigestAlgorithmName();
      
        iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7 sgn = new iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7(null, chain, digestAlgorithmName, false);

        byte[] hash = iText.Signatures.DigestAlgorithms.Digest(inputStream, digestAlgorithmName);
        byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
        byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
        sgn.SetExternalSignatureValue(signatureHash, null, signature.GetSignatureAlgorithmName());

        encodedSig = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);

        return encodedSig;
    }
}

Example answer digidentity code from request "Retrieve identity information"
{
  "key": {
    "status": "enabled",
    "algo": [
      "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"
    ],
    "len": 2048
  },
  "cert": {
    "status": "valid",
    "certificates": [
      "MIIG1TCCBL2gAwIBAgI...V2yYRGjwk/GQsq67A=="
    ],
    "issuerDN": "C=NL,O=Digidentity B.V.,organizationIdentifier=NTRNL-27322631,CN=TEST Digidentity Personal Qualified CA",
    "serialNumber": "7867EX1A9M6PLE3A8C4K6751Q05ADD3C",
    "subjectDN": "C=NL,SN=Doe,GN=John,serialNumber=4exa3441-m601-44p6-9416-ls695cid3775,CN=John Doe",
    "validFrom": "20220209095106Z",
    "validTo": "20230209095106Z"
  },
  "authMode": "implicit",
  "multisign": 1,
  "lang": "en-US",
  "SCAL": "2"
}

Updated 5/24/24
So, if I don't need to create an empty container and add it to the file, then I shouldn't use the SignDeferred method either? I get hash:
string digestAlgorithmName = signature.GetDigestAlgorithmName();
byte[] hash = iText.Signatures.DigestAlgorithms.Digest(inputStream, digestAlgorithmName);
byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
    

I use this sh to create a hash for the CSC API:
    using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
{
    byte[] hashBytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(sh);
    string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    hashInfos.Add(new HashInfo
    {
        Hash = base64Hash,
        UniqueId = file.UniqueId,
        FileName = file.Name
    });
}

And after that, I execute:
byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);

and set the signature received from Digidentity:
sgn.SetExternalSignatureValue(signatureHash, null, signature.GetSignatureAlgorithmName());


Please share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis.

@mkl I uploaded the file to Google Drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BBQ5q-FjoEzGZYPs2BfuSPjB47UTPPW/view?usp=sharing
I dont know how attached the file on comment
This is a file that is signed according to the scheme that I described in the question

@mkl I added new file with prod data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWG9czxEBUdzem2-Ya0Aa3iXV-17Krvw/view?usp=sharing

The first example file signature appears to be encrypted with a non-matching key. The second example file signature at least is encrypted with the key matching your certificate but the hash signed by it is not the hash of the signed attributes of your signature. Thus, the second one is better (keep the change you applied to get it), but there still is an issue. I'll take a look at your code, I have an idea what to look for.

Considering the code in your question, it appears to have signed your first file but not the second one: AddSignatureToPdf adds a signature container signed by an arbitrary RSA key unrelated to the certificate you set as signer certificate. As for your second file the generating code has been improved to use the correct private key, please update your question to show that code.

@mkl I have updated the code. Now it matches the code used to sign the second file and the prod data from Digidentity was used

"I have updated the code. Now it matches the code used to sign the second file and the prod data from Digidentity was used" - That's unlikely. Your code still creates the signature using a private key that's generated randomly without relation to the certificate. The second file, though, was signed using the private key matching the certificate. The chances are nearly zero that the randomly generated private key equals the correct private key.

That being said, how does Digidentity give you access to the correct private key? Has the certificate being created based on a certificate request you generated yourself (and, therefore, still have the private key for)? Or did they send you some key store? Or is it on some external device? Or even a web service?

@mkl
I interact with Digidentity using their API:
https://docs.digidentity.com/
Specifically:
For authentication: Authentication -> Authorization code -> Passwordless login
For signing: Signing -> CSC API
I receive the certificate in response to the Retrieve identity information request in the following form(i added this code in the post)
They also provided the data necessary for authorization in their system. But they did not provide any private key

"CSC API [...] They also provided the data necessary for authorization in their system. But they did not provide any private key " - You mention the CSC API. The CSC is the Cloud Signature Consortium who have published the CSC API for signing using signing services in the cloud. Thus, you'll never hold an actual private key for your certificate. Instead, you'll have to send the data to sign (i.e. your GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes or their hash) to them in a web request to retrieve a response containing the signature bytes. The page https://docs.digidentity.com/ explains how to do that.

@mkl  I don't understand, what am I doing wrong? I am sending the file hash, after creating a container for the digital signature in it, for signing. After that, I receive a response from Digidentity in the form of a signature string and try to add this signature to the existing container.
Could you please tell me what I need to do to pass the validation?

"I don't understand, what am I doing wrong? I am sending the file hash, after creating a container for the digital signature in it, for signing." - I don't see you sending or receiving anything at all in the code you post. But if you mean the hashes you collect in ConvertHashToBase64, they are doubly incorrect. They would have been useful for external signature files but with iText you try to create integrated signatures which work differently: For integrated signatures the document hash is not calculated over the whole prepared PDF but only over it minus the placeholder for the signature!

... You actually already calculate that document hash in your MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign method as byte[] hash. But even this hash is not to be signed directly. Instead it is one value among many in a set of so called authenticated (or signed) attributes. You retrieve the bytes of those attributes in MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign as byte[] sh. So you have to send the hash value of sh for signing and use the result as byte[] extSignature.

@mkl  So, in the EmptySignature function, after creating the container, I need to also create a hash using GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes and pass this hash to the ConvertHashToBase64 function, from where it will then be sent to Digidentity. After that, I should use the string received from Digidentity for the SignDeferred method?

Well, strictly speaking, the easiest change would be to simply inside MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign calculate the hash of sh, send it to the CSC API, retrieve the result, and use it. Is there a specific reason you want to have hashes elsewhere?

There is no specific reason to have the hash in another place.
I just don't understand you are saying that the simplest way would be to send the hash directly in the MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign method:
byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
and then use the string from Digidentity for sgn.SetExternalSignatureValue.

But creating an empty container is necessary? and this hash sh should be formed after adding the empty container, right?
The hash formation is needed first for the Request sign authorization (Digidentity) request, and then the same hash for the signing in the Sign hash (Digidentity) request. Therefore, I need to form it and store it for use in both API methods.

I tried sending this hash to Digidentity:
byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
and received an error from the Digidentity service - prepare_sign_failed - Unable to call certificate. In most cases this indicates that the hash value specified is invalid.
So, the hash is not valid.
Sorry, but could you please explain once more the sequence I should use?

"I tried sending this hash to Digidentity: byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);" - that is not a hash! You first have to calculate the hash of that, just as I've proposed in my previous comment.

"But creating an empty container is necessary?" - no. The whole code you posted is unnecessarily complicated. What I proposed merely was the simplest way given the code you show to make it runnable. Thereafter is purpose optimization.

@mkl Could you please take a look? I have updated the post - under Updated 5/24/24.
Could you please tell me if I have understood the logic correctly?

"I have updated the post - under Updated 5/24/24." - I'm not completely sure I correctly understand what you're saying there. In particular you only prepare some data for the CSC API but don't say whether or when you send it to the API and whether you use the result. And then you call signature.Sign(sh) but signature in your code is a PrivateKeySignature object based on a random private key, so this signing doesn't make any sense.

@mkl Can I write to you via email or any other messenger that is convenient for you? There are character limits here in the comments. Is this possible?
When the solution is working, I will definitely add it and mark your answer as correct.

I received your mail. I'll respond later.

In comments we tried to fix your existing code to properly sign PDFs with a CSC API signature service. That did not work. For a different approach, therefore, I show in this answer a more simply code frame in which you can include your actual CSC communication. Unfortunately you did not share that code, so I cannot include it here in the answer code.
When signing a PDF with iText, you should in general go for a single-step approach (yes, underneath still multiple steps are necessary, but iText handles that for you).
Only under special circumstances it makes sense to consider a multi-step approach that at first only prepares a PDF for signing, calculates its hash, and saves it somewhere, and that later injects a signature container somehow retrieved in the meantime into that prepared PDF by means of deferred signing.
Thus, the following code uses a single-step approach that requests each signature separately from your service. Furthermore, as your use of the CSC API v1 returns naked signed hashes (not fully fledged PKCS#7/CMS signature containers), it lets iText build the signature container.
In this approach all the code interacting with your service is enclosed in a single IExternalSignature implementation:
class ServiceSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    public string GetDigestAlgorithmName()
    {
        return "SHA-256";
    }

    public string GetSignatureAlgorithmName()
    {
        return "RSA";
    }

    public ISignatureMechanismParams? GetSignatureMechanismParameters()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public X509CertificateBC[] GetChain()
    {
        // Insert your code that retrieves your certificate chain from your signature
        // service and returns it as X509CertificateBC[].
    }

    public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        byte[] hash = SHA256.HashData(message);

        // Insert your code that retrieves a signature for that hash value
        // from your signature service and returns it.
    }
}

(SignWithService helper class)
You can then use that ServiceSignature class to simply sign a single PDF in one step:
ServiceSignature signature = new ServiceSignature();

using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, mem, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
    signer.SignDetached(signature, signature.GetChain(), null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    File.WriteAllBytes(resultFile, mem.ToArray());
}

(SignWithService test SignWithIExternalSignature)
(Actually you don't need a MemoryStream here, you can use a file stream directly.)
To sign multiple files, simply put the using structure into a loop.
Obviously you can optimize the ServiceSignature class a bit. For example, you can fetch the certificate chain only once from your service and cache the result. Also you can first query your service for supported hashing and signing algorithms and make the GetDigestAlgorithmName, GetSignatureAlgorithmName, and GetSignatureMechanismParameters return values depend on your choice from them.

Thank you very much for your answer! As soon as I check it along with requests to digidentity, I will definitely write about the result

I successfully passed the validation thanks to your response. I am immensely grateful for your help!
